# Extract all rows in dataframe having same date

Tags: python, pandas

I've got a Dataframe composed by data gathered by monitoring activities with a timestep of a minute.

The dataframe has a first column of datetimes with this format:

```
2018-04-15 00:00:00+02:00
2018-04-15 00:01:00+02:00
...
2018-04-18 23:59:00+02:00
```

followed by columns of the monitored values.

How do I create a new dataframe which contains all the rows of data collected during a given day, for example `2018-04-15`, from `00:00` to `23:59`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First make sure that the `dtype` of the column is datetime.

`df['Column Name'].dtype`

If the output is 'O' or other. Do:

`df['Column Name'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Column Name'])`

Next we have two options,

1 - either we can split the date and time into seprate columns and use them as `multi_index`:

```
df['Date'] = df['Column Name'].dt.date
df['Time'] = df['Column Name'].dt.time

df.set_index('Date','Time',drop=True)

#to access all rows for a particular date

df['Place your required date']
```

2- or use `loc`:

```
df_temp = df.loc[df['Date'] == 'Your Date']
```

Answer (score 0):

You can group by day periods with `pd.Grouper(freq='D')`. The result is a generator which yields name-dataframe-pairs:

Example dataframe:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.random(10000), index=pd.date_range('15.05.2018', periods=10000, freq='min'))

df.head()
                            0
2018-05-15 00:00:00  0.693383
2018-05-15 00:01:00  0.158559
2018-05-15 00:02:00  0.752485
2018-05-15 00:03:00  0.990374
2018-05-15 00:04:00  0.768559
```

you can iterate over the groups, i.e. over all the days by writing

```
for name, group in df.groupby(pd.Grouper(freq='D')):
    print(f'Day: {name}', f'\ndataframe:\n{group.head()}\n')
```

result (*again printing the `head()` of each day only for brevity*):

```
Day: 2018-05-15 00:00:00 
dataframe:
                            0
2018-05-15 00:00:00  0.693383
2018-05-15 00:01:00  0.158559
2018-05-15 00:02:00  0.752485
2018-05-15 00:03:00  0.990374
2018-05-15 00:04:00  0.768559

Day: 2018-05-16 00:00:00 
dataframe:
                            0
2018-05-16 00:00:00  0.553670
2018-05-16 00:01:00  0.091114
2018-05-16 00:02:00  0.226051
2018-05-16 00:03:00  0.826132
2018-05-16 00:04:00  0.817027

.
.
.
```

---

***EDIT:***
The same for a dataframe with standard index and datetime values in a separate column:

Example dataframe:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'A': np.random.random(10000), 'date': pd.date_range('15.05.2018', periods=10000, freq='min')})

df.head()
          A                date
0  0.238412 2018-05-15 00:00:00
1  0.612181 2018-05-15 00:01:00
2  0.204367 2018-05-15 00:02:00
3  0.246023 2018-05-15 00:03:00
4  0.987291 2018-05-15 00:04:00
```

iterating over the groups generated by passing the date-column-name to `pd.Grouper()`:

```
for name, group in df.groupby(pd.Grouper(key='date', freq='D')):
    print(f'Day: {name}', f'\ndataframe:\n{group.head()}\n')
```

result (*again printing the `head()` of each day only for brevity*):

```
Day: 2018-05-15 00:00:00 
dataframe:
          A                date
0  0.238412 2018-05-15 00:00:00
1  0.612181 2018-05-15 00:01:00
2  0.204367 2018-05-15 00:02:00
3  0.246023 2018-05-15 00:03:00
4  0.987291 2018-05-15 00:04:00

Day: 2018-05-16 00:00:00 
dataframe:
             A                date
1440  0.039037 2018-05-16 00:00:00
1441  0.762621 2018-05-16 00:01:00
1442  0.158714 2018-05-16 00:02:00
1443  0.132067 2018-05-16 00:03:00
1444  0.277562 2018-05-16 00:04:00

.
.
.
```

Comment: Thanks, this is close to what i need but i cannot understand why, using my dataframe instead of your 'df', it doesn't compute it.
Probably it has something to do with the fact that my Dataframe has dates on the first column while in your example, timestep is used as index. is it possible?

Comment: Yes, indeed. You can change that by setting the `date`-column as index with `df = df.set_index('date')` _(assumed your date-column is named `date`...)_

Comment: If it still doesn't work your date data might not be of type `datetime` but just `string`. You can change that by using `df.index = pd.to_datetime(df.index)`

Comment: However, you don't really _need_ to have a datetime-index. You can pass the column name for grouping to `pd.Grouper`, too. See my edit.